# Client side logging supported both on desktop and iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, logging

I need some logging mechanism for logging  JavaScript errors or other client side information into a local file for desktop and sent to server side in case of iPad.How to maintain consistency in such a framework to maintain logs both locally and server side i.e in iPad local log should not be generated but it should be sent to server side and in desktop local log should be generated and not sent on server side.

P.S. Framework should work in chrome , Firefox and safari

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `JavaScriptCore.framework`.? Check if it helps you to log errors.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder I have not used JavaScriptCore framework but will it support both desktop and iPad for logging.

Comment: I'm not sure but I suggest you to check post as it could be helpful for the community members.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder JavaScriptCore.framework is C based framework so its quite difficult for me to implement in my java based project...kindly suggest any other java based logging framework